# Fluent NHibernate 1.1 and castle.core 2.5.0.x together issue

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'm using the latest stable build of [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) ver 1.1. Now in the application I'm also using `castle.core` for [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Now the problem is using them together. In Visual Studio castle.core says ver. 2.5.1.0 but in Windows Explorer "details" for the same DLL file it says 2.5.1.2121. I have tried both numbers in assembly binding in the `web.config`, to switch away from ver. 1.1.0.0 which the Fluent NHibernate castle.core references, but not with much luck.

Any suggestions to solve this issue? I do not want to build any of the assemblies myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. I used the MVC contrib project and this was the source to the problem, the Windsor controller factory. I wrote my own and removed the reference, only a few lines of code, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I came across with this was to get the nhibernate.bytecode.castle source and build it against the latest source for castle.core - alternatively you could use a nhibernate.bytecode.linfu instead.

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt Fluent NHibernate against the latest [Castle Project](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Project) core and Fluent NHibernate beta2. Now it works.